# Elements of the field $F_2[x] / (x^3 + x + 1)$

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

What do elements of the field $F_2[x] / (x^3 + x + 1)$ look like?
I know this is isomorphic to $F_8$, and that its elements have max degree of 2, so that leaves me with
$0$, $1$, $x$, $x^2$, $x+1$ , $x^2+x$, $x^2+1$, $x^2+x+1$. Therefore, is this the same as the field $F_2[x] / (x^3 + x^2 + 1)$?

Comment: Do you know upto isomorphism there is only one unique field of order p^n ?

Comment: I don't... although if I do that would make the two fields the same?

Comment: not the same,but isomorphic !

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I meant! And consulting my notes we did prove this to be true. Thanks Arpit!

Comment: I am writing this in answer so that this question won't come in unanswered questions list !

Comment: It would be a good exercise for you to find an explicit isomorphism between the two fields of order $8$ coming from the two polynomials.

Comment: Hint: Show that (over any field) $\alpha$ is a zero of $x^3+x+1$ if and only if $1/\alpha$ is a zero of $x^3+x^2+1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I've done that!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I recently did that as an exercise in class. :)

Comment: Good! Then you can follow up and show that the isomorphism here maps $\alpha=x+\langle x^3+x+1\rangle$ to the **inverse** of $x+\langle x^3+x^2+1\rangle$. To find that inverse show that in the latter field 
$$1+\langle x^3+x^2+1\rangle=(x+\langle x^3+x^2+1\rangle)(x^2+x+\langle x^3+x^2+1\rangle).$$ Or, if we denote $\alpha=x+\langle x^3+x+1\rangle$ and $\beta=x+\langle x^3+x^2+1\rangle$, then the isomorphism could map $\alpha\mapsto 1/\beta=\beta+\beta^2$. Note: the isomorphism is not unique! There are three of them, so a classmate may have a different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Upto isomorphism there is unique field of order $p^n$ for any prime $p$ and any natural number $n$. This simply follows from the fact that any such field is splitting field of the polynomial $x^q-x$ where $q=p^n$