# Isomorphic quotients of polynomial rings over finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, finite-fields

What are the elements of $\mathbb{F}_3[X]/(X^3-3)$?

A similar question was posted here: [Elements of the field $F_2[x] / (x^3 + x + 1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169886/elements-of-the-field-f-2x-x3-x-1), but it doesn't explain why the elements of that field look that way.

> Anyway the problem I'm trying to solve here is to determine for which $p\in\{2,3,5,7\}$ the rings $\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(X^3-3)$ and $\mathbb{F}_p[T]/(T^3+2)$ are isomorphic.

I don't see how the linked post can help with this question, though.

Comment: Hints: $5$ is the easiest. For $7$ the quotient in both cases has to be a field. Why?

Comment: @GeorgLehner I'm supposed to do this without using field theory. Also why is 5 the easiest and not 2?

Comment: What is $-3$ mod$5$ ?

Comment: @GeorgLehner 2, so only two elements for p=5?

Comment: It seems to me you have a misunderstanding how quotients work: Take for example the first quotient $\mathbb F_p[X]/(X^3-3)$. You get the quotient by taking the polynomial ring, and setting every multiple of $(X^3-3)$ equal to zero. So for example $X^3 - 3 \equiv 0$, i.e. $X^3 \equiv 3$, or as another random example $X^4 + X^3 +1 \equiv 3X + 3 + 1$.

Comment: @GeorgLehner Yes, I understand it better now, thanks to you and user26857 here below! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints.** For $p=2$, they are not isomorphic. (Look for nilpotents.)
Similarly for $p=3$.
They are equal for $p=5$, and isomorphic for $p=7$ (since both polynomials are irreducible over $\mathbb F_7$.)

Comment: What can I do with nilpotents?

Comment: @LucasGeorge To see if one of the rings has one and the other don't.

Comment: Okay, and how do I find one?

Comment: @LucasGeorge Look at the ring $\mathbb F_2[T]/(T^3)$. What do you think about the (third power of) residue class of $T$?

Comment: Nilpotent because $T^3=0$?

Comment: @LucasGeorge Right.

Comment: But what is nilpotent in $\mathbb{F}_2[T]/(T^3+2)$?

Comment: @LucasGeorge Do you know that $2=0$ in $\mathbb F_2$?

Comment: Oooooh. So $T$ is nilpotent there as well?

Comment: @LucasGeorge Now what about $\mathbb F_2[X]/(X^3+1)$? Does this have non-zero nilpotents?

Comment: It does not? Though I can't immediately see why

Comment: @LucasGeorge Certainly not! If $X^3+1\mid f(X)^m$, then $X^3+1\mid f(X)$ since $X^3+1=(X+1)(X^2+X+1)$ is a product of two irreducible polynomials.

Comment: Okay, then all is clear for 2,3 and 5. My last question is why does irreducibility of the polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_7$ imply an isomorphism?

Comment: @LucasGeorge Now I think you have to use that finite fields with the same number of elements are isomorphic.

Comment: Okay thank you very much for all your help! :)